# How do I set the value of an input after doing an Axios get request?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that represents a form for entering book data, e.g. title/author/etc.

If an ID is present, the component will make an API call to the API server, and get the book data.

What I'm trying to accomplish basically, is getting the record from the API server, and then setting the form fields to those values, so that the form is populated with data for the user to edit.

I have a method called `loadBook` which makes an API call to get the book data. The method works, it gets the record, it sets the state, but the form inputs do not seem to pick up that the state has changed.

What do I need to do to get the form populated with the record that was just fetched?

```
import React from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import {
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import FormBase from "../FormBase";

export default class BookForm extends FormBase {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formFields: {
                title: '',
                author_id: null,
                cover_image: null
            },
            authors: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadAuthors();
        if (this.props.id) {
            this.loadBook()
        }
    }

    loadBook = () => {
        Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/books/${this.props.id}`).then(response => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                let formFields = Object.assign({}, prevState.formFields)
                formFields['title'] = response.data['title']
                formFields['author_id'] = response.data['author_id']
                return {formFields}
            })
        })
    }

    loadAuthors = () => {
        Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/authors`).then(response => {
            this.setState({authors: response.data})
        })
    }

    render() {
        let authors = this.state.authors.map(author => {
            return <option key={author.id} value={author.id}>{author.last_name}, {author.first_name}</option>
        })
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); this.props.handleSubmit(e, this.state.formFields, true)}}>
                {this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to="/admin/books" /> : null}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} type="text" className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="author">Author</label>
                    <select name="author_id" onChange={this.handleFieldChange} className="custom-select" size="5">
                        {authors}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-file form-group">
                    <input name="cover_image" type="file" onChange={this.handleFieldChange} className="custom-file-input" id="customFile" />
                    <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile">Cover Image</label>
                </div>
                <button style={{marginTop: '1rem'}} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your state simply like so:

```
this.setState({formFields:
    {
        ...this.state.formFields,
        title: response.data['title'],
        author_id: response.data['author_id']
    }
})
```

Comment: In the code that I wrote, the state is set successfully, that part works, the problem is that the form inputs do not recognize the change that occurred. If I open up the react devtools, I can see that the state has been successfully updated properly, and contains the proper values. The problem is that they don't get populated into the form.

Comment: for title input, you set the value as `this.state.title`. isnt `title` in `this.state.formFields` object?

Comment: That isn't the problem. The problem is that React does not automatically read the state object to pre-populate form fields. Which means that I need to do it manually. I think I've found a solution, which I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

I essentially followed [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) on uncontrolled components.

I added attributes for each form field using `React.createRef()`, and then on the form inputs you link the ref object like `ref={this.author_id}`. Then, you can do `this.author_id.current.value = response.data.author_id` and the input's value will then be set. This won't trigger `onChange` though, so you'll need to update the state too.

```
import React from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import {
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import FormBase from "../FormBase";

export default class BookForm extends FormBase {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formFields: {
                title: '',
                author_id: null,
                cover_image: null
            },
            authors: [],
        };
        this.title = React.createRef();
        this.author_id = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadAuthors();
        if (this.props.id) {
            this.loadBook()
        }
    }

    loadBook = () => {
        Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/books/${this.props.id}`).then(response => {
            console.log(this.author_id)
            this.author_id.current.value = response.data.author_id
            this.title.current.value = response.data.title
            this.setState(prevState => {
                let formFields = Object.assign({}, prevState.formFields)
                formFields['title'] = response.data['title']
                formFields['author_id'] = response.data['author_id']
                return {formFields}
            })
        })
    }

    loadAuthors = () => {
        Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/authors`).then(response => {
            this.setState({authors: response.data})
        })
    }

    render() {
        let authors = this.state.authors.map(author => {
            return <option key={author.id} value={author.id}>{author.last_name}, {author.first_name}</option>
        })
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); this.props.handleSubmit(e, this.state.formFields, true)}}>
                {this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to="/admin/books" /> : null}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                    <input name="title" ref={this.title} value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} type="text" className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="author">Author</label>
                    <select name="author_id" ref={this.author_id} onChange={this.handleFieldChange} className="custom-select" size="5">
                        {authors}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="custom-file form-group">
                    <input name="cover_image" type="file" onChange={this.handleFieldChange} className="custom-file-input" id="customFile" />
```